# generate soap fault when required parameter is not passed

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

In soap API, I have set few parameters as required by adding **minOccurs="1".**

is it possible to generate soap fault if I am not passing required parameters in Soap CALL.

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Are you asking for php generation of the soap fault or are you asking if you can emulate generation of a soap fault in soapUI?

Comment: My apologies if I could not present my que properly. My que was I have created one WSDL. in that I have defined some parameters as required. Now I am making soap call. Not providing parameters which I had set as required. Would it result in soap Fault? or I need to check in my soap server manually and generate soap fault if parameter not passed. Plz Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return soap fault from server. 
you can simply wrap your client call in try block and catch this soap exception as it is in ur code..